# Values not updating in database for registration page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, macos

I'm trying to make a registration page using PHP but the values are not being updated in the table and no errors are shown. I'm using a Mac for this. I have set up a XAMPP server, Have a folder named `Lab` in `htdocs` folder. Inside the `Lab` folder I have a file named `register.php` -

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","User Registration");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    session_start();
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['name']);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
    $password=md5($password);
    $sql="INSERT INTO User(Name,Email,Password) VALUES('$name','$email','$password')";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $_SESSION['message']="You are now logged in";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base>
    <link href="register.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="blogger.ico"/>
    <title>Blog</title>

</head>
<body background="background.png">
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="login.html">Log In</a>
            <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <form action="">
                <h3>Register</h3>
                <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
                <br>
                <input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" id = "name" required>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <br>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id = "email" required>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="email"><b>Password</b></label>
                <br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="password"><b>Re-enter Password</b></label>
                <br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
                <br>
                <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

This is my database structure - 
[Databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlCEc.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is always false. It is because there are no `name="submit"` in your form. Try adding `else { echo 'error'; }`

Comment: Added `name="submit"` to the `<input type="submit"` but did not change anything.

Comment: Try adding `else{}`

Comment: One more thing, add `method="POST"` to the form. If I'm not mistaken, the default of form is `GET`

Comment: Oh yes, I had forgotten about that. It worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some modifications necessary:**

1) You have not set any method for `<form>`, so default method is `GET` and you are trying to access variables with `$_POST`. So, please make `<form method="post">`

Explanation:

***Case GET method:***

`<form method="get">`

This is default method.

If no method is specified, this is the method.

But, not preferred (especially in registration/login) because all form submitted data is shown on url.

The variables submitted in the form will be accessible through:

`$var = $_GET['variableName'];`

***Case POST method:***

`<form method="post">`

The variables submitted in the form will be accessible through:

`$var = $_POST['variableName'];`

`post` method is secure one and variables submitted in this method are not shown on url.

This preferable method.

Now, you can choose exactly which method do you prefer.-

2) Also, PHP variables are case-sensitive. You are using

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

And form element's name is not there. Make it `name="submit"`

Comment: Thanks for this :). Solved now.